# как сделать сдвиг вправо без учета знака C++?

Tags: c++

Вот такое выражение выдает ошибку синтаксиса:

```
 opcode >>> temp;
```

В C++ нет встроенного оператора беззнакового сдвига вправо? Надо самому делать с помощью масок?

Comment: `((unsigned)opcode) >> temp`?

Comment: @Abyx: Он не размножает знаковый бит, ЕМНИП.

Comment: @Abyx, когда старший бит заполняется нулями, независимо от того было ли число положительным или отрицательным. Ну я получаю машинную интсрукцию как целое число из 32 бит. Мне нужно получить opcode - это старшие 5 бит. Но затем этот opcode мне надо показать так, как будто это беззнаковое число из 5 бит. Поэтому их нужно сдвинуть на 27 знаков вправо. Получившееся число и будет opcode. Но это если старшие биты нулями заполнятся и не будут влиять на число.

Comment: А если единицами, то я получу отрицательное число

Comment: Хотя у меня не может быть отрицательных опкодов.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Возможно, вам лучше для этого использовать битовое поле.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Если вы изначально будете в качестве типа переменной `opcode` использовать беззнаковый тип, например `unsigned int`, то и результат `opcode >> temp;` будет желаемым, в случае же необходимости использования знакового типа переменной, то, как и указал _VladD_, воспользуйтесь следующим: `(unsigned)opcode >> temp;`, либо вообще использовать `std::bitset`.

Comment: @Abyx, потому что изначальная то интсрукция то может начинаться с единицы, никто ей не запрещает. Если я буду использовать unsigned, я прочитаю неправильное значение с самого начала. И тогда уж точно ни о каком правильном опкоде говорить не придется

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо, интересно про битовое поле, не знал о таком. Хотя сейчас почитал, я же вроде бы так и делаю.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Должно быть что-то такое: `struct Instruction {  unsigned int opcode : 5; unsigned int flags: 1; ... }; ... Instruction inst; ... opcode = inst.opcode;`

Answer (score 4):

Применяется ли знаковый или беззнаковый сдвиг - зависит от знаковости левого операнда. Так что просто приведите его к необходимому типу.

И учтите, что в правом сдвиге знакового типа распространение знакового бита (распространять его или заполнять нулями) зависит от компилятора.

Правда, пока не слышал, чтобы знаковый бит в этой ситуации где-то не распространялся...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int opcode = 0xFF000000;
    cout << (opcode >> 27) << endl;
    cout << ((unsigned int)opcode >> 27) << endl;
}
```

дает (VC++ 2015)

```
-1
31
```